# How to add a float or integer number (i.e 255) to a raster layer?

Tags: raster

Is there any code to add a float or integer value with a raster layer? I can easily do mathematical operations between two raster data. But I am unable to do the same between float or integer number and  raster layer. For example if want to execute (256-band3), how can I execute?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try the raster package in R. Something like:

```
r = raster("foo.tif") + 255
writeRaster(r,"foo.tif",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: it is not so much difficult. use the following expressionIMapAlgebraOp mapAlgebraOp;

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of [FME](http://www.safe.com) then you can use the RasterExpressionEvaluator transformer.

In this case (256-band3) the expression would be simply:

```
256-A[2]
```

(FME labels bands as 0,1,2 rather than 1,2,3).

The nice thing is that it also allows IF statements, so you can work up to complex statements like:

```
if ((A[0]+A[1]+A[2])==0, 255, A[0])
```

[This page on FMEpedia](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Examples-using-the-RasterExpressionEvaluator-Transformer) has a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try RasterCalc plugin for QGis.